# Read data from 125kHz tag and write into 433MHz remote

Tags: nfc, read

At the moment, I am opening the garage door via the 125khz key tag. I purchased a 433mhz remote. Also, I have a tool to read/write data from tags and I have used it in the past to copy key tags.

I planned to use the tool for read/write data that works on multiple frequencies to **read data** (serial) from 125khz tag, switch the tool to 433mhz mode, and then **write read data** to a 433mhz remote.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I assume that the tool does not care about operating frequency and that it stores read data to a temp memory so that I can use this data and program a remote.

Is this feasible or it's Sci-Fi?

Comment: What is the point of all of this? The 125 kHz tag reader still won't be able to read the 433 MHz remote even if it has the same basic data loaded into it.

Comment: @Andyaka The reader that opens the gate (I see only 1 such device in front of the garage) reacts to both, tags and remote. I see some people having a remote, aside from tags. So I assumed that the reader obviously rads both 125khz and 433mhz signals. Does this make any sense?

Comment: This is very unlikely to work.  Questions on the usage of consumer products are off topic here because sufficient engineering detail cannot be provided.

Comment: _"The reader reacts to both, tags and remote... So I assumed that the reader obviously reads both 125khz and 433mhz signals. Does this make any sense?"_ - yes, it makes sense. But that doesn't mean the 433MHz remote sends the same signal as the tag. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I want to have a remote :) and I do not have another 433mhz remote to clone it. So I am trying to see if I can read 125khz tag and use this data to program 433mhz remote.

Comment: `So I assumed that the reader obviously reads both 125khz and 433mhz signals. Does this make any sense?` ... no, it makes no sense ... an assumption that there are two separate readers would make sense

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you say that your garage door opener has a 433 MHz receiver, but you don't have the matching remote. Unfortunately without one it may be impossible to determine what protocol and codes it uses (probably a rolling code which is very different from an RFID tag).

However you could use your remote to send a signal to a separate receiver which then emulates the tag, placed close to the door reader. The wireless link could then use whatever protocol and codes you like (eg. a standard remote tx/rx set). The only question then is, can you 'clone' the tag?

Another option might be to tap into the 433 MHz receiver circuit inside the door controller, then use that signal to operate the door directly from inside the controller (bypassing the original decoder section). Or if that signal is not available, install a separate receiver and use its signal to operate the door control circuit.

Comment: Pretty sure the asker does not own the receiver or the location of its installation.  This is a people problem not a technical problem, eg, the asker hasn't been able to persuade those in charge to issue the type of transmitter they want and that others apparently have.

Comment: Yeah, the OP seems to be confused about what is being controlled. First it's 'the garage door', then it's 'the gate'. If OP doesn't own it then any modifications are out of the question, and perhaps cloning the remote too (security risk?). In which case paragraph one stands.